# Heroku "The timeout specified has expired" In laravel application with basic AUTH

Tags: laravel, authentication, heroku

We have deployed our application over heroku with basic laravel auth functionality. There not any loop or any heavy query.
Following are the parameters posted to /login function.

- _token   s7rKa0Ve2XODZcagW1K26qrqoOFyyuCWfxtEcrQI
- email    test@gmail.com
- password 12341234

LoginController Code

```
public function __construct()
{
    $this->middleware('guest')->except('logout');
}

/**
 * The user has been authenticated.
 * Method copied from"Illumunate\Foundation\Auth\AuthenticateUsers.php"
 * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
 * @param  mixed  $user
 * @return mixed
 */
protected function authenticated()
{

    if( Auth::user()->role == '1') return Redirect('members');

    if( Auth::user()->role == '2' ) return Redirect('assignments');

}
```

and following error is showing in heroku log file.

> 2018-11-06T09:14:30.519786+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H12
>   desc="Request timeout" method=POST path="/login"
>   host=polar-meadow-18285.herokuapp.com
>   request_id=1cafc4c1-8f72-4b04-854b-c315f9636935 fwd="39.59.198.150"
>   dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=30000ms status=503 bytes=0
>   protocol=https 2018-11-06T09:15:00.578424+00:00 app[web.1]: [Tue Nov
>   06 09:15:00.577937 2018] [proxy_fcgi:error] [pid 246:tid
>   140561109444352] (70007)The timeout specified has expired: [client
>   10.109.225.219:31977] AH01075: Error dispatching request to : (polling), referer: https://polar-meadow-18285.herokuapp.com/login
>   2018-11-06T09:15:00.578672+00:00 app[web.1]: 10.109.225.219 - -
>   [06/Nov/2018:09:14:00 +0000] "POST /login HTTP/1.1" 504 247
>   "https://polar-meadow-18285.herokuapp.com/login" "Mozilla/5.0
>   (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.12; rv:63.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/63.0
>   2018-11-06T09:28:20.973811+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET
>   path="/login" host=polar-meadow-18285.herokuapp.com
>   request_id=ac62bbad-2516-455b-bff7-22764cdce842 fwd="39.59.198.150"
>   dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=19ms status=200 bytes=6961
>   protocol=https

i am unable to figure it out. Your thoughts will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

you will have to make a .procfile and you can follow the official documentation for further help.

```
https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/getting-started-with-laravel
```